# Convcode in optimx / Synth in R

Tags: r, convergence

I've been using the Synth package (which uses optimx for the optimization) and I can't find the answer to whether Synth gives a non-convergence error when it doesn't converge. I can see in the help file for optimx that, by default, it does not save the failures (i.e. those answers that do not converge) so I am guessing that by default it does not pass those failures onto Synth; however, I want to be sure that the answers I am getting have converged. Is there a way to be sure of this through the convcode() setting or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the code and it does not set a control value for `save.failures` so It should use the default behavior of `optimx` whicho is FALSE as you already knew. Here are the relevant calls to `optimx` in the `synth()` code.

```
rgV.optim.1 <- optimx(par = SV1, fn = fn.V, gr = NULL, 
    hess = NULL, method = optimxmethod, itnmax = NULL, 
    hessian = FALSE, control = list(kkt = FALSE, starttests = FALSE, 
        dowarn = FALSE, all.methods = all.methods), X0.scaled = X0.scaled, 
    X1.scaled = X1.scaled, Z0 = Z0, Z1 = Z1, quadopt = quadopt, 
    margin.ipop = Margin.ipop, sigf.ipop = Sigf.ipop, 
    bound.ipop = Bound.ipop)

....

rgV.optim.2 <- optimx(par = SV2, fn = fn.V, gr = NULL, 
    hess = NULL, method = optimxmethod, itnmax = NULL, 
    hessian = FALSE, control = list(kkt = FALSE, 
      starttests = FALSE, dowarn = FALSE, all.methods = all.methods), 
    X0.scaled = X0.scaled, X1.scaled = X1.scaled, 
    Z0 = Z0, Z1 = Z1, quadopt = quadopt, margin.ipop = Margin.ipop, 
    sigf.ipop = Sigf.ipop, bound.ipop = Bound.ipop)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured.